# To many incorrect reviews after no reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

So, I went to do some reviewing today and I saw the 'review banned' banner. The past time that I have got it made sense, I had failed several audits and got kicked out.

But this time was different. I didn't have that pop up yesterday, and I haven't done any reviews today at all.

Could this be the algorithm deciding to kick me off based on my history? Did somebody hack my account? Did I do something else I shouldn't have?

Other questions that deal with this topic don't cover unexplainable (on my side) suspensions after not failing any reviews.

Comment: So... you can get blocked for 2 things: 1- missing too many audits. 2-sometimes a wrong edit or post gets through review. Then a diamond moderator sees it. They can (and do) impose a ban on everyone who reviewed that particular item. Is there a "to see an example of a wrong review" somewhere in the warning?

Comment: It could have been a manual review ban from a moderator.  Was there a custom message or review link on the ban page?

Comment: Did you read the message you got from the review ban explaining why you were banned?

Comment: Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12922957. The message was the 'to many incorrect reviews' default message.

Comment: Looks like a manual ban. You should not have approved that edit. "Comment: Modified Code, changed some type errors, and added `If oShp.HasTable Then`". Edits should **never** modify code.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's just wrong.  There are cases where it's appropriate for an edit to change code, this just isn't one of those cases.

Comment: @Servy Really? Most of the allowed edits in [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246) don't actually modify the code itself.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, **most**, not **all**.  It's *rare* for there to be an appropriate edit to code.  That's different than saying you should *never* modify code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You have made too many incorrect reviews. After only failing one?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268156/you-have-made-too-many-incorrect-reviews-after-only-failing-one)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were manually banned by a moderator from review for two days for approving [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12922957).

That edit was flagged as one that should not have been approved, because it fixed the problems with the code in the question itself, rather than in an answer. It invalidated the question / answers as a result.

Be very careful when reviewing edits that make changes in code. If you're not familiar with the subject matter, I recommend either skipping the review or declining the edit if substantial changes are being made.

Comment: I get it now. For some reason all I saw was formatting edits. My fault.

Comment: Seems pretty harsh to ban someone for approving that review when 3 of 4 people approved it.